# Cómo puedo encapsular los objetos en python para evitar la creación de variables nuevas dentro de las instancias?

Tags: python, programación-funcional

Me explico con el siguiente código:

```
class EsUnCirculo:

    def __init__(self, radio = 1):
        self.__radio = radio

    @property
    def radio(self):
        return self.__radio

    @radio.setter
    def radio(self, valor):
        self.__radio = valor
```

---

```
EsUnCirculo_uno = EsUnCirculo()

EsUnCirculo_dos = EsUnCirculo(2)

print("EsUnCirculo_uno contiene: ",EsUnCirculo_uno.__dict__)

print("EsUnCirculo_dos contiene: ",EsUnCirculo_dos.__dict__)

EsUnCirculo_uno.radio = 3

EsUnCirculo_dos.radoi = 4
```

Supongamos que cometo un error de typo acá (cosa que lamentablemente es muy frecuente en mi). Debería darme un error indicando que la clase no contiene esa variable/atributo/property. Incluso agradecería un warning. Pero, en cambio, la crea dentro de la instancia :/.

**VER LA SALIDA.**

Esto no es bueno para mi OCD. Cómo evito esto?

```
print("EsUnCirculo_uno contiene: ", EsUnCirculo_uno.__dict__)

print("EsUnCirculo_dos contiene: ", EsUnCirculo_dos.__dict__)
```

LA SALIDA ES:

```
EsUnCirculo_uno contiene: {'_EsUnCirculo__radio': 1}

EsUnCirculo_dos contiene: {'_EsUnCirculo__radio': 2}

EsUnCirculo_uno contiene: {'_EsUnCirculo__radio': 3}

EsUnCirculo_dos contiene: {'_EsUnCirculo__radio': 2, 'radoi': 4}
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta de [tag:programación-funcional]? No tiene nada qué ver.

Answer (score 4):

Usar `__slots__` como plantea @ChemaCortes es sin duda la forma más directa y con menos sobrecarga de conseguir lo que deseas, solo hay que tener en cuanta dos aspectos:

- La serialización con pickle puede fallar por usar protocolos antiguos. Esto se soluciona simplemente usando el último protocolo disponible  (`pickle.dump(instance, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`. El futuro Python 3.8 por defecto usará el protocolo 4 que es el último protocolo definido para Python 3.
- La mayor limitación está en la herencia dado que en un mismo árbol de herencia no puede haber más de una clase con `__slots__` no vacío. Hay una interesante  respuesta en el sitio en inglés sobre el uso de `__slots__` que puede ser interesante al respecto:

  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/7131499

Otra alternativa a `__slots__` es seguir usando `__dict__` pero jugando con `__setattr__` de forma que se evite cualquier intento de definir un nuevo atributo en una instancia de forma dinámica. Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, por ejemplo similar a como hacemos con `__slots__` definimos un atributo de clase que contendrá  los métodos permitidos a modo de lista blanca y en el método `__setattr__` comprobamos si se intenta definir un atributo  no permitido. Lo que no me gusta de esta vía es que al ser un atributo de clase se comparte entre instancias, si heredamos de esta clase base y añadimos en una de sus hijas un atributo a la lista blanca, este será también permitido en el resto de clases hijas...

Dentro de las posibilidades voy a dejar dos opciones junto a un ejemplo con clases derivadas:

- Crear una clase de la que poder heredar, definiendo un atributo de instancia encargado de mantener una lista blanca de atributos permitidos, forzando al método `__setattr__` a lanzar una excepción si se viola ésta:

  ```
  class Freeze:
      def __init__(self):
          self._allowed_attrs = set()

      def add_allowed_attrs(self, *args):
          self._allowed_attrs.update(args)

      def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
          if attr != "_allowed_attrs" and attr not in self._allowed_attrs:
              raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute '{}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, attr))
          object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)


  class Circulo(Freeze):
      def __init__(self, radio=1):
          # Imprescindible llamar al inicializador de la clase padre
          super().__init__()
          self.add_allowed_attrs("radio", "_radio")
          self._radio = None
          self.radio = radio

      @property
      def radio(self):
          return self._radio

      @radio.setter
      def radio(self, valor):
          self._radio = valor



  class CirculoHija1(Circulo):
      def __init__(self, radio, center):
          super().__init__(radio)
          self.add_allowed_attrs("center")
          self.center = center


  class CirculoHija2(Circulo):
      def __init__(self, radio, color):
          super().__init__(radio)
          self.add_allowed_attrs("color")
          self.color = color
  ```
- Usando un decorador e introspección para solo habilitar la creación de atributos al método `__init__`:

  ```
  import inspect                                                                                                                             


  # Decorador
  def freeze_class(cls):

      # Funcion que va a sobreescribir a __setattr__
      def frozen_setattr(self, attr, value):

          # Se comprueba si el atributo no existe y no es __init__ el que intent definirlo lanzamos la excepcion
          if not hasattr(self, attr) and inspect.stack()[1][3] != "__init__":
              raise AttributeError("{} object has not attribute '{}'".format(cls.__name__, attr))

          # En caso contrario llamamos al metodo __setattr__ de la clase base
          object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

      # Sobreescribimos el metodo __setattr__ de la clase
      cls.__setattr__ = frozen_setattr

      # Retornamos la clase 'decorada'
      return cls                                                                                                                             

  # Decoramos la clase en la que queramos implementar la característica                                                               
  @freeze_class                                                                  
  class Circulo:
      def __init__(self, radio=1):
          self._radio = None
          self.radio = radio

      @property
      def radio(self):
          return self._radio

      @radio.setter
      def radio(self, valor):
          self._radio = valor   


  class CirculoHija1(Circulo):
      def __init__(self, radio, center):
          super().__init__(radio)
          self.center = center


  class CirculoHija2(Circulo):
      def __init__(self, radio, color):
          super().__init__(radio)
          self.color = color
  ```

  La pega que tiene este método es que fallará en implementaciones de Python cuyo intérprete no tenga soporte para `stack frame` (importante si usamos implementaciones que no sea cpython como pypy, IronPython, Jython, etc).

El comportamiento de ambas opciones es similar:

> ```
> >>> c = Circulo(5)
> >>> c.radio = 13
> >>> c.radi = 43
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
>     c.radi = 43
>   File "test.py", line 42, in __setattr__
>     raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute '{}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, attr))
> AttributeError: Circulo object has no attribute 'radi'
>
> >>> c1 = CirculoHija1(5, (0, 7))
> >>> c1.radio = 7
> >>> c1.center = 2, 5
> >>> c1.foo = 14
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
>     c1.foo = 14
>   File "test.py", line 42, in __setattr__
>     raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute '{}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, attr))
> AttributeError: CirculoHija1 object has no attribute 'foo'
>
> >>> c2 = CirculoHija2(5, "verde")
> >>> c2.radio = 2
> >>> c2.color = "azul"
> >>> c2.center = 5, 8
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
>     c2.center = 5, 8
>   File "test.py", line 42, in __setattr__
>     raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute '{}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, attr))
> AttributeError: CirculoHija2 object has no attribute 'center'
> ```

Comment: Muy educativa tu respuesta. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me gustó mucho tu primera solución. Lo único que yo cambiaría sería quitar la redundancia de usar "radio" y "_radio" (Esta última permitiría el acceso directo a ella también). Preferiría usar "__radio" por lo que habría que hacer: self.add_atributos_permitidos("_Circulo__radio", "radio") y quitaría las líneas que contienen self-_radio = None y la siguiente y sólo usaría la self.__radio = radio

Answer (score 3):

En python puedes delimitar los atributos de una clase utilizando el atributo *mágico* `__slots__` ([slots](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)) que sería una lista de los atributos permitidos.

Pero su uso no es fácil de entender si no se sabe cómo funciona los descriptores y los diccionarios de una instancia (`__dict__` y `__weakref__`). Sería muy largo de explicar.

Estudiando tu caso concreto, el único atributo que necesitas tener es `__radio`. La propiedad `radio` que estás definiendo no pertenece al diccionario de la instancia ya que las propiedades se definen como descriptores de la clase.

Añadiendo `__slots__`:

```
class EsUnCirculo:

    __slots__ = ['_EsUnCirculo__radio']

    def __init__(self, radio = 1):
        self.__radio = radio

    @property
    def radio(self):
        return self.__radio

    @radio.setter
    def radio(self, valor):
        self.__radio = valor
```

Dará error si alguien intenta dar un valor a algo que no sea `.radio`. Pero tiene dos problemas a tener en cuenta:

1. El atributo `__radio` seguirá accesible como atributo `_EsUnCirculo__radio`, algo que es inevitable por propio funcionamiento de python.
2. Tu instancia carece de diccionario, no tendrá atributo `__dict__`. Se puede añadir a `__slots__`, pero volveríamos al problema inicial, ya ue se permitiría de nuevo crear atributos dinámicamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: En efecto, muchas gracias. Esto resuelve mi problema. Como comentaste, pierdo el __dict__ (lo cual no es un problema ya que de necesitarlo en cualquier momento sólo tendría que comentar la línea __slots__) pero al menos no me permite crear el "radoi" cuando lo intento. De esta forma puedo escribir mi programa sin temor a cometer un typo en una variable de instancia y perder tiempo por no encontrar un bug producto de una letra invertida :/. Voy a leer más acerca de los descriptores. Ya voté por tu respuesta pero aún no tengo la reputación necesaria para que se refleje. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque no tengas *diccionario*, siempre puedes ver los atributos de un objeto con la función `dir(obj)`. Personalmente, votaría la respuesta de @FJSevilla ya que está mucho más completa.